# How to bitwise shift in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, operators, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

How do I bitwise shift right/left in VB.NET? Does it even have [operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h9cz2eb%28VS.80%29.aspx) for this, or do I have to use some utility method?

Comment: It's right [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d9yb87a(VS.80).aspx) mate, just down on the list from the link you posted!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

VB.NET has had bit shift operators ([`<<`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7haw1dex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dezyht83%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) since 2003.

Comment: I think a code example would be in order, e.g. for `UInteger`.

Comment: Including an example that works for the most significant bit.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [<<](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7haw1dex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [>>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dezyht83%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) operators, and you have to specify how many bits to shift.

```
myFinal = myInteger << 4   ' Shift LEFT by 4 bits.
myFinal = myInteger >> 4   ' Shift RIGHT by 4 bits.
```

You can also use it as a unary operator...

```
myFinal <<= 4     ' Shift myFinal LEFT by 4 bits, storing the result in myFinal.
myFinal >>= 4     ' Shift myFinal RIGHT by 4 bits, storing the result in myFinal.
```

Comment: What type is `myFinal`? Unsigned or signed? How many bits? `Integer`? `UInteger`?