# How to set any single bit in a Short

Tags: vb.net, types, bit-manipulation

If varShort in VB.NET is a Short and varBit is a value from 0 to 15, how can I set the bit in varShort identified by varBit without disturbing any of the other bits in varShort?

My problem, of course, is with the most significant bit, bit 15. Since varBit is determined at runtime, the solution must work with any bit number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bitshift operators, [<<](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7haw1dex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [>>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dezyht83%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), to turn on the bit you want (and put this value in `varValue`), and then bitwise Or `varShort` and `varValue`

There is information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417645/how-to-bitwise-shift-in-vb-net) about the bitshift operators in VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

Setting the sixteenth bit of a `Short` will cause an overflow exception because [Short](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tb7bdw6.aspx) is a [signed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) type. Do you have any reason not to use the unsigned counterpart [UShort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x68bebe2.aspx)?

**Edit**

If you really want to stick with `Short`, this function will set the sixteenth bit:

```
Function setNthBit(ByVal number As Short, ByVal bit As Short) As Short
    Dim mask As UShort
    mask = 2 ^ bit
    If mask > Short.MaxValue Then
        Return (Short.MinValue + number) Or mask
    Else
        Return number Or mask
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: My third-party software requires the Short datatype.  Thanks for the details of your answer.

Comment: This does not compile with Strict On: ***Error 7 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'*** (the line with "mask = 2 ^ bit").