# How do I split a 16-bit value into two 8-bit values in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, 16-bit, 8-bit

I have a 16-bit value like this:

```
 0000000000000011
```

I want to split this in two 8-bit values like:

```
 00000000    and    00000011
```

The 16-bit value is a variable, `byte_val1`, which is a unsigned 16-bit integer.

How can I do this in VB.NET?

Comment: have you looked at http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/bitops01.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417645/how-to-bitwise-shift-in-vb-net ?

Comment: actually i tried the `<< >>` operators but didn't succeed to get `00000011`

Comment: did just use >>, or with with AND ? `result = (val_16 >> 8) AND &HFF` ? (&H -> 0x)

Comment: got it solved by @Guffa .. so thanks to him and to every one thanks for your time guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `BitConverter` class:

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(byte_val1)
```

Now `bytes(0)` contains the lower byte (00000011) and `bytes(1)` contains the higher byte (00000000).

Answer (score 5):

To obtain lower 8 bits, you need to and it with `11111111`, or `0xff`
To obtain upper 8 bits, you need to and it with `1111111100000000`, or `0xff00`
Then to an arithmetic left shift exactly 8 bits.

I have not done Visual Basic in a while, but the idea is as follows:

```
word a = 1930392;
byte alower = a & 0xff;
byte ahigher = (a & 0xff00) >> 8;
```

Oh, here's a code I made with three textboxes named `a`, `alower`, `aupper` and a button `btnDoIt`:

```
Private Sub btnDoIt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDoIt.Click
    Dim localA = Integer.Parse(a.Text())
    Dim localALower = localA And &HFF
    Dim localAUpper = (localA And &HFF00) >> 8

    alower.Text = localALower
    aupper.Text = localAUpper
End Sub
```

Sidenote: `(localA And &HFF00) >> 8` is equivelent to `(localA >> 8) And &HFF`

Comment: Technically, the AND operation shouldn't be necessary before doing the bit-shift.

Comment: (localA And &HFF00) >> 8; is necessarily like that. Otherwise I would need to write ((localA >> 8) And &HFF), you can draw yourself a picture if you like, it isn't too difficult. 0xff00 and 0x00ff are not equal

Comment: Bit shifts in VB.NET are not circular, so when you shift a 16 bit number 8 bits to the right, the 8 right-most bits are discarded.  Therefore, there's no need to zero them out first.  The only reason to do that would be if you had a larger number, such as a 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple bitshift should work if you want certain byte(s) from any value (32 bit, 64 bit, 128 bit, etc..).

The simplest way is to `AND` ("binary AND", also written as "&") the source with the bits you want and then to shift it as many times as needed to get the desired value.

```
Dim initial as Integer = &H123456 ' Hex: 0x123456
Dim result as Byte = (initial AND &H00FF00) >> 8
'result = 0x34
```

and if you would like to join them again it's even simpler:

```
Dim initial as Integer = &H123456 ' Hex: 0x123456
Dim result_a as Byte = (initial AND &H00FF00) >> 8
Dim result_b as Byte = (initial AND &HFF0000) >> 16
Dim final as Integer = (result_a << 8) or (result_b << 16)
'final = 0x123400
```