# How do I split a 16-bit value into two 8-bit values?

Tags: rust

I have u16 value and want to convert it into two u8 values to put it into u8 array, the same as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110586/how-do-i-split-a-16-bit-value-into-two-8-bit-values-in-vb-net).

```
0000000000000011 -> 00000000    and    00000011
```

How would I do that in a convenient way?

Comment: You can do this language-agnostically with bitshifts and masking: the top byte will be `x >> 8` and the bottom byte will be `x & 0xff`.

Comment: yes, got it, will do something like: value >> 8 value & 0b0000_1111

Comment: You can also get it using these functions on u16: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.to_be_bytes

Comment: @AntonBlomström this is what I was looking for. Both worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting the answers provided by @apilat and @Anton into code:

#### Bit Shifting - verbose style

This can be accomplished in a couple of different ways.  I actually think that bit shifting is a little clearer, as no thought needs to be given to whether I need to worry about endianness.

Spelling out each:

```rs
fn shift_verbose_split_u16(short_16: u16) -> [u8; 2] {

    let high_byte: u8 = (short_16 >> 8) as u8;
    let low_byte: u8 = (short_16 & 0xff) as u8;

    return [high_byte, low_byte];
}
```

#### Bit Shifting - idiomatic style

The above code can be reduced to a one-line function:

```rs
fn shift_idiomatic_split_u16(short_16: u16) -> [u8; 2] {
    [(short_16 >> 8) as u8, (short_16 & 0xff) as u8]
}
```

#### Using `to_be_bytes()`

Using `to_be_bytes()` certainly is the simplest solution.  Using this solution, you have to realize that you really want to use the big-endian call, regardless of the underlying cpu's architecture:

```rs
let [high, low] = short_16.to_be_bytes();
```

#### Grouping the code into one file:

```rs
fn main() {
    let short_16: u16 = 0x3f23;
    
    // verbose bit shifting
    let [high, low] = shift_verbose_split_u16(short_16);
    assert_eq!(high, 0x3f);
    assert_eq!(low, 0x23);

    // idiomatic bit shifting
    let [high, low] = shift_idiomatic_split_u16(short_16);
    assert_eq!(high, 0x3f);
    assert_eq!(low, 0x23);

    let [high, low] = short_16.to_be_bytes();
    assert_eq!(high, 0x3f);
    assert_eq!(low, 0x23);

    println!("High: {:#0x?}, Low: {:#0x?}", high, low);   
}

fn shift_verbose_split_u16(short_16: u16) -> [u8; 2] {

    let high_byte: u8 = (short_16 >> 8) as u8;
    let low_byte: u8 = (short_16 & 0xff) as u8;

    return [high_byte, low_byte];
}

fn shift_idiomatic_split_u16(short_16: u16) -> [u8; 2] {
    [(short_16 >> 8) as u8, (short_16 & 0xff) as u8]
}
```

#### Output:

```rs
High: 0x3f, Low: 0x23
```