# C++ to VB.NET conversion

Tags: c++, vb.net

I am getting stuck on converting the following C++ lines to VB.NET.  Most of these appear to involve bit shifting, however, I need to get the `<<` and `>>` out of the code as well as an equality check:

```
   nn = n << 1

   m >>= 1

   istep = mmax << 1

   wr=(wtemp=wr)*wpr-wi*wpi+wr;  //what is the check for wtemp=wr?
```

What would the VB.NET conversions look like?

Comment: Duplicate, at least in regards to bit shifting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417645/how-to-bitwise-shift-in-vb-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. VB.NET supports bitshifting using the same `<<` and `>>` operators as C and C++.

   ```
   Dim nn As Int32 = n << 1
   m = m >> 1
   istep = mmax << 1
   ```
2. `wr=(wtemp=wr)*wpr-wi*wpi+wr;` is not doing any "checking" - it's an inline assignment. In VB.NET you cannot put an assignment inside an expression so you must do it separately.

   ```
   wtemp = wr
   wr = wtemp * wpr - wi * wpi + wr
   ```

   I would add parenthesis to keep it readable because not everyone can remember exact operator precedence (like myself):

   ```
   wtemp = wr
   wr = ( wtemp * wpr ) - ( wi * wpi ) + wr
   ```